# python sqlite3 - cursor vs connections - executing UPDATE statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I am having trouble with executing UPDATE statements.
In the code below when I write `con.execute()` it writes to the database, but if I write `c.execute()` it doesn't write to the database.
Long comment is where the code in question lies.

Most Relevant snippet

```
def write_data(con, c):
    geolocator = Nominatim()
    table = c.execute('SELECT * FROM playerdata WHERE birth_place_long is null AND birth_place is not null').fetchall()
    for i in table:

        try:
            location = getgeo(i[4], geolocator)
            lat, long = location.latitude, location.longitude
        except:
            print(i[0])
            '''  changing to c.execute doesnt work '''
            con.execute('UPDATE playerdata SET birth_place_lat = ?, birth_place_long = ? WHERE id = ?', (1, 1, i[0]))
            print("failed" + i[1] + " " + i[2])
            con.commit()
        else:
            c.execute('UPDATE playerdata SET birth_place_lat = ?, birth_place_long = ? WHERE id = ?', (lat, long, i[0]))
            print(i[1] + " " + i[2])
            con.commit()
    con.close()
```

Full code below:

```
import csv
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import sqlite3
import socket
import geopy.exc
import pandas as pd

def connect_db():
    con = sqlite3.connect('c:/s_db2.sqlite3')
    c = con.cursor()
    return con, c


def getgeo(place, geolocator):
    try:
        location = geolocator.geocode(place)
        return location
    except (socket.timeout):
        return getgeo(place, geolocator)
    except geopy.exc.GeocoderTimedOut:
        return 0


def write_data(con, c):
    geolocator = Nominatim()
    table = c.execute('SELECT * FROM playerdata WHERE birth_place_long is null AND birth_place is not null').fetchall()
    for i in table:

        try:
            location = getgeo(i[4], geolocator)
            lat, long = location.latitude, location.longitude
        except:
            print(i[0])
            '''  changing to c.execute doesnt work '''
            con.execute('UPDATE playerdata SET birth_place_lat = ?, birth_place_long = ? WHERE id = ?', (1, 1, i[0]))
            print("failed" + i[1] + " " + i[2])
            con.commit()
        else:
            c.execute('UPDATE playerdata SET birth_place_lat = ?, birth_place_long = ? WHERE id = ?', (lat, long, i[0]))
            print(i[1] + " " + i[2])
            con.commit()
    con.close()

while True:
    write_data(connect_db()[0], connect_db()[1])
    print("************* re-running ****************")
```

Comment: Are you getting any particular error?

Comment: Thanks for the edit Anthony.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line in your loop:

```
write_data(connect_db()[0], connect_db()[1])
```

`connect_db()` is being called twice in the same call of `write_data()`.

This is similar to:

```
con_1, c_1 = connect_db()
con_2, c_2 = connect_db()

write_data(con_1, c_2)
```

You are mixing instances of the connections with cursors of other instances.

instead you may want:

```
con_1, c_1 = connect_db()

write_data(con_1, c_1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't know why I did that, but that is a good catch.

Answer (score 0):

The conn is using a connection instance which has its own setup, i.e autocommit. But, a curso, you need to define the autocommit set, or rather to persist the commit after executing the sql.

i.e use `con.commit()` after `with con: c.execute()`

NB, if this logic is executing after the try-catch block (i.e exception) you probably need to rollback before executing this one.